# What is the MathNet equivalent of MATLAB prod(v)?

Tags: c#, matlab, math.net

I am porting some MatLab code to MathDotNet / C#

What is the function to return each element in a vector multiplied together?

In MatLab i can do prod(v)

What is the equivalent of this in MathDotNet?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it exists, but you can use LINQ to accomplish it.

```
int total = vector.Enumerate().Aggregate((product, next) => product * next);
```

Comment: hmm - is there a recommended approach for extending MathDotNet - i.e. LINKQ vs MathDotNet's internal iterators?